# Sharepoint: How do i find a mail enabled list, if i only have the email?

Tags: sharepoint

I know the email from a mail enabled list, with I have no idea where the list lies.
How do i find the list to which the email belongs to?

Comment: What do you mean a mail enabled list?  And couldn't you just search based on whatever is in the email?

Comment: I did, but it doesnt find anything?

Answer (score 4):

The code below works if you know the site collection of the list. If you don't know that, you can easily modify the code to loop a complete web application (or even a complete farm):

```
using System;
using Microsoft.SharePoint;

namespace FindListByEmail
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string siteUrl = "[complete this]";
            string email = "[complete this]"; // only the part before the @

            using (SPSite site = new SPSite(siteUrl))
            {
                foreach (SPWeb web in site.AllWebs)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        foreach (SPList list in web.Lists)
                        {
                            if (list.CanReceiveEmail)
                            {
                                if (list.EmailAlias != null && list.EmailAlias.Equals(email, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
                                {
                                    Console.WriteLine("The email belongs to list {0} in web {1}", list.Title, web.Url);
                                    Console.ReadLine();
                                    return;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    finally
                    {
                        if (web != null)
                        {
                            web.Dispose();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: One question: is it possible that the list has been deleted and the email contact still remains?

Comment: Depending on the way you have things set up, SharePoint will create an entity in active directory when you email-enable a list. So yes, it's possible that the list has been deleted and the entity in AD is still there.

Answer (score 0):

To find All Incoming E-Mail Enabled Lists and Libraries in SharePoint, You can use PowerShell , C# code or SQL Server Query!

Find the PowerShell Script, SQL Query and C# code here: http://www.sharepointdiary.com/2011/06/find-all-incoming-email-enabled-lists.html#ixzz2aKvhRTDN

Comment: Note that link-only answers are discouraged, SO answers should be the end-point of a search for a solution (vs. yet another stopover of references, which  tend to get stale over time). Please consider adding a stand-alone synopsis here, keeping the link as a reference.